# Would phpBB break if I move it from one folder to another? Can I use mod_rewrite to redirect requests for that forum from old folder to new one?

Tags: htaccess, redirects, mod-rewrite, phpbb

Please note that I have installed dynamic web pages (PHP) in the directory *public_html/old/* in order to create the web site *www.example.com*. Actually I have created a PHPBB forum and thus the URL of a topic is:

`http:// www.example.com/old/viewtopic.php`

or the URL of the index file is:

`http:// www.example.com/old/index.php`

What I would like to do is to change the name of directory “old” to “new”. I have been consulted that it can be done by editing the file *.htaccess* that exists in the directory *public_html* and write inside:

```
Redirect permanent /old http://example.com/new
```

Could you please let me know if is this correct or should I write
www.example.com instead of example.com. Moreover could you please let me know whether this effects any aspect of my web site?

In addition I have been informed that if I change the name of the directory then it may break my web site (since I will have changed the path or location of the script) unless I configure it to work correctly. Could you please let me know what  should the configurations be?

Answer (score 1):

From the [phpBB documentation](https://www.phpbb.com/support/documentation/3.0/adminguide/acp_general.php) if you move the directory in which it is installed you may need to change the `SCRIPT PATH` as defined in the configuration file.  It looks like you will only need to do this if you also have the `FORCE SERVER URL SETTINGS` option set, otherwise phpBB adapts to whatever directory you have it in.

Your redirect code looks correct.  As you note, you may want to add a `www` into it.  If your preferred URL is with the "www", then use it in the redirect.